# Z3 optimization Issue?

Tags: z3

I wanted to find the maximum value of a variable under some simple constraints. But the result is not the optimum (max). Indeed, we can add another constraint and the solver still find another solution...
I also tried this example in python with the Optimize solver and maximize(r), but I get the same result. I also checked the upper bound (with the upper method) and I get the same erroneous result (4).

I'm not used to playing with the optimization feature of Z3, I generally only make proof; that's why I'm almost sure that the mistake is mine...

For now, I use a loop over the check-sat in python and iteratively add a constraint (r > result). It's working but it's neither elegant nor efficient...

```
; (set-logic QF_LIA)
(define-const x Int 9)

(define-const a Int 3)
(define-const b Int 4)
(define-const c Int 4)
(define-const d Int 5)

(declare-const i Int)
(declare-const j Int)
(declare-const t Int)
(declare-const r Int)

(assert (>= i 0))
(assert (>= j 0))

(assert (= t (+ (* i b) (* j d) 1)))
(assert (= r (+ (* i a) (* j c) c)))

(assert (<= t x))

(maximize r)
(check-sat)
;sat
(get-model)
;(model 
;  (define-fun i () Int
;    0)
;  (define-fun j () Int
;    0)
;  (define-fun r () Int
;    4)
;  (define-fun t () Int
;    1)
;)
(get-value (r))
;((r 4))
(assert (> r 4))
(check-sat)
;sat
(get-model)
;(model 
;  (define-fun i () Int
;    2)
;  (define-fun j () Int
;    0)
;  (define-fun r () Int
;    10)
;  (define-fun t () Int
;    9)
;)
```

```
$ z3 --version
Z3 version 4.8.7 - 64 bit
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this. When I run your program, it gives me `r = 10`, and if I then further assert `(> r 10)`, then I get `unsat`.

However, I'm using z3 4.8.13, and I noticed that your z3 version is rather old, 4.8.7; which dates to late 2019. See if you can upgrade: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases

(The latest released version is 4.8.12; though you can also directly build from their GitHub sources, which will be tagged 4.8.13.)

Please report back if you still see the issue after upgrading.